# JavaScript firing too many events?

Tags: javascript

The handle `mousemove` events are amongst 3 `<div>`s which are nested inside each other. Can't seem to find the issue which is causing too many events to get fired.

```js
(function() { 
  var boxes = [ 
    document.getElementById("box1"),
    document.getElementById("box2"),
    document.getElementById("box3"),
  ]; 

  boxes[0].addEventListener(
    "mousemove", function(event) { console.log("Box 1"); }
  ); 
  boxes[1].addEventListener(
    "mousemove", function(event) { console.log("Box 2"); }
  ); 
  boxes[2].addEventListener(
    "mousemove", function(event) { console.log("Box 3"); }
  );
})();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you post a [mcve] using a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)? Do you want events to only fire on the object the mouse is currently hovering on?

Comment: Hi @ggorlen, thanks, yep thats exactly what i want! thanks :)

Comment: Are those events firing every single time the mouse moves just slightly? If you just want when it hovers then replace with: .addEventListener("mouseover", function(event)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the events to fire when you hover then that event is called 'mouseover'

```js
boxes[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
  console.log("Box 1");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `event.stopPropagation()` function. As you have said that div are nested,
So,

> When an event happens on an element, it first runs the handlers on
>   it, then on its parent, then all the way up on other ancestors which is called **Event Bubbling**.

You can read about it [here](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing).

Look at the following example,

```js
let box1 = document.querySelector(".box1");
let box2 = document.querySelector(".box2");
let box3 = document.querySelector(".box3");

box1.addEventListener("click",()=> alert("Box1"));
box2.addEventListener("click",()=> alert("Box2"));
box3.addEventListener("click",()=> alert("Box3"));
```

```css
.box1,.box2,.box3 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  Box 1
  <div class="box2">
    Box 2
    <div class="box3">Box 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you click on Box3, Box2 and Box1 alert also shown.
The Reason behind is that, [Event Bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)

You can Stop It by Using `event.stopPropagation()` function

```js
(function() {
  var boxes = [
    document.getElementById("box1"),
    document.getElementById("box2"),
    document.getElementById("box3"),
  ];

  boxes[0].addEventListener("mouseover",
    function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      console.log("Box 1");
    }
  );
  boxes[1].addEventListener("mouseover",
    function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      console.log("Box 2");
    }
  );
  boxes[2].addEventListener("mouseover",
    function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      console.log("Box 3");
    }
  );
})();
```

```css
#box1,#box2,#box3 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  Box 1
  <div id="box2">
    Box 2
    <div id="box3">Box 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**OR,**

You can add the event on the parent element only once, like this

```js
(function() {
  var parentBox = document.getElementById("box1");

  parentBox.addEventListener("click",
    function(event) {
      let targetDiv = event.target;
      switch(targetDiv.id) {
       case "box1" : console.log("Box 1");break;
       case "box2" : console.log("Box 2");break;
       case "box3" : console.log("Box 3");break;
      }      
    },true);
  
})();
```

```css
#box1,#box2,#box3 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  Box 1
  <div id="box2">
    Box 2
    <div id="box3">Box 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```js
boxes[0].addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropogation();
  
  console.log("Box 1");
});
```